# SQL How to select columnA and columnB where columnB has a distinct value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called **emp**

```
id| name  
1 | jon  
1 | trav  
2 | jon  
2 | jon    
3 | jon
3 | jon
```

I would like to select only the distinct **id**s that have the value "jon" in the **name** column.
I do not want the **id**s where there is one value "jon" and another value as something else within the **name** column.

The output should look like this:

```
id|name  
2 |jon  
3 |jon
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried already?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the following

The logic is to find out the total count of names and the count of names by id where name='jon' and if it matches return the output.

Here is one way to do this.

--Using max since we need an aggregate function when grouping by id, to bring any other columns.

```
create table t(id int, name varchar(50))

insert into t 
select 1,'jon'  union all
select 1,'trav' union all 
select 2,'jon'  union all
select 2,'jon'  union all  
select 3,'jon'  union all
select 3,'jon'

select id,max(name)
  from t 
 group by id
having count(distinct name)=count(distinct case when name='jon' then 1 end)

+----+-----------+
| id | max(name) |
+----+-----------+
|  2 | jon       |
|  3 | jon       |
+----+-----------+
```

Db Fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=637432cca3238285cb888889e1fa6ec7

Comment: @maine . . . It works, but it seems overly complicated to me.

Comment: am i missing something here. how can this be made simpler

Answer (score 0):

A NOT EXISTS clause will work well here, and perform well too.

```
SELECT id, name
FROM tbl t
WHERE name = 'jon'
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tbl a WHERE a.id = t.id AND a.name != t.name)
```

Comment: Using GROUP functions for this query is unnecessary and it creates a temporary table which is a MySQL scalability issue...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT id, name
FROM emp
WHERE name = 'jon'
GROUP BY id, name
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't solve the problem for a bigger table, but the logic helped a lot

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
select id, min(name) as name
from emp
group by id
having min(name) = max(name) and min(name) = 'Jon';
```

Comment: it should be group by id rather than group by name?